# jQuery Hide Background of Menu when at top

Tags: jquery, html, menu

I'm trying to remove the background (background only, not text) of the menu when it's at the top of the browser.

For example, take a look at how this website has done it (scroll down then back up to see it's effect): http://www.thoughtspot.com/

My jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/s6mLJ/2266/

```
// Hide Header on on scroll down
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
if (didScroll) {
    hasScrolled();
    didScroll = false;
}
}, 600);

function hasScrolled() {
var st = $(this).scrollTop();

// Make sure they scroll more than delta
if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
    return;

// If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
// This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
    // Scroll Down
    $('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
} else {
    // Scroll Up
    if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
        $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
    }
}

lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: The example is same as your requirement, can you expain what has to be done.

Comment: Think there is a jQuery plugin for that https://plugins.jquery.com/bootstrap-autohidingnavbar/

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your setinterval function

```
 if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0 ) {
    $('header').css('background-color','rgba(0,0,0,0)');
    }  else { 
     $('header').css('background-color','rgba(29,31,35,0.92)');
}
```

see jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s6mLJ/2310/

or : http://jsfiddle.net/s6mLJ/2311/ a little more smooth

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    // Make sure they scroll more than delta
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;

    // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
    // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){

        // Scroll Down
        $('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
        }
    }

    lastScrollTop = st;
    if($(window).scrollTop()==0){
        $('header').css('background-color', 'rgba(29,31,35,0)');
    } else {
        $('header').css('background-color', 'rgba(29,31,35,0.92)');
    }
}
```